Platonistic interpretation of Gödel (theorem 14.2, I in Kunen).
On page $41$ in Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs", after proving

If $\phi(x)$ is any formula in one free variable, $x$, then there is a sentence $\psi$ such that

$$\sf{ZF} \vdash \psi \leftrightarrow \phi(\ulcorner \psi \urcorner).$$
Kunen says that

...; for some sentence $\psi$, $$\sf{ZF} \vdash \psi \leftrightarrow \neg \chi(\ulcorner \psi \urcorner).$$

He points out that then (atleast "platonistically"), no formula $\chi(x)$ can say "$x$ is a true sentence".
My issue is, what exactly must $\chi(x)$ say to derive this contradiction (assuming there was such a formula)? Naively, $\chi(\ulcorner\psi \urcorner)$ would say "$\ulcorner \psi \urcorner$ is a true sentence", but $\ulcorner \psi \urcorner$ is not a sentence, but an encoding in natural numbers, that represents $\psi$. Should it not rather be that $\chi(x)$ says "$x$ is a Gödel number of a true sentence" for $\chi(\ulcorner \psi \urcorner)$ to make sense?

Yes, it should say "$x$ is a Gödel code of a true sentence."

@QiaochuYuan Although I originally upvoted your answer, I think spaceisdarkgreen is right, it is really superflous, since $\psi$ is really in the metatheory.

There's not really any issue with saying that the hypothetical formula would express "$x$ is a true sentence" as opposed to "$x$ is the Gödel code of a true sentence". When we express ideas about formulas and sentences internally to set theory, we do that through some coding scheme, but that's the same in principle as how we express any other aspect of math in set theory (e.g. the natural number zero is "coded" as the empty set), and we don't usually call attention to the fact that the relevant mathematical objects are "coded" when we talk about a sentence of set theory expressing some idea about topological spaces or functions or what-have-you.
It can certainly be useful to be explicit about the "codedness" sometimes for pedagogical purposes, though, since there's risk of confusing internal formulas with formulas in the metatheory.

As for what this hypothetical formula would actually need to say to get a contradiction, the only thing we're assuming here is just Tarski's T-schema... that for any sentence $\varphi,$ $\chi(\ulcorner \varphi\urcorner)\leftrightarrow\varphi$ holds (either platonistically or provably in $\sf ZF$), which of course would be contradicted by the fact that there's a sentence $\psi$ such that $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash\psi \leftrightarrow\lnot\chi(\ulcorner\psi\urcorner).$
Even though we're doomed to failure in this this narrow case, it's still worth thinking about how one would go about constructing such a formula and there are several positive results worth noting:

In $\sf ZF$, it's possible to express truth for sentences relative to a set uniformly... i.e. there's a formula $\chi(x,y)$ such that for any sentence $\varphi,$ $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash\forall A(\chi(\ulcorner \varphi\urcorner, A)\leftrightarrow \varphi^A$).
In $\sf ZF$, it's possible to express truth for any fixed level of the Lévy hierarchy. i.e. for a given $n\in\mathbb N$ there is a formula $\chi_n$ such that for any $\Sigma_n$ sentence $\varphi,$ $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash\chi_n(\ulcorner \varphi\urcorner)\leftrightarrow\varphi$ (which avoids contradiction since there's no reason to expect that the sentence given by diagonalizing $\lnot \chi_n$ would be $\Sigma_n$).
In Morse-Kelley, a theory of both sets and proper classes, there is a truth predicate for sentences of set theory, i.e. a formula $\chi(x)$ in the language of class-set theory, such that for any sentence $\varphi$ with no class variables/quantifications $\mathsf{MK}\vdash\chi(\ulcorner \varphi\urcorner)\leftrightarrow\varphi$ (which avoids contradiction since there's no reason to expect the sentence produced by diagonalizing $\lnot\chi$ wouldn't quantify over proper classes).


Yeah, no, I think I get the idea; my quibble is that Kunen writes that $\chi(x)$ says "$x$ is a true sentence", but "$\ulcorner \psi \urcorner$ is a true sentence" is nonsensical, since $\ulcorner \psi \urcorner$ is not a sentence.

@Ben123 What could be a better representation of "$\phi$ is a true sentence" than asserting "$\phi$"? (I believe Tarski said something like "'Snow is white' is true if and only if snow is white.")

I'm not sure I follow; well, I understand your (Tarskis) point, but I fail to connect them to this context, tbh; well, they are sort of similar, in a sense, but I can't exactly say I understand what you are trying to get across.

@Ben123 I don't understand your quibble. When we talk about formulas in formalized set theory, we talk about their Godel codes... it's just like talking about any other mathmatical construct we formalize it's reduntant to say "the Godel code of a sentence". It's like saying "ZF proves our set theoretical coding of the real numbers satisfies our encoding of the intermediate value property" or something like that.

@Ben123 (My point was just that the T-schema gives a reasonable property we'd expect a purported predicate that expresses "$x$ is a true sentence" to have. Sorry, I guess I didn't understand what you were objecting to until I reread it.)

Regarding your former post; It is not my present understanding that one only talks about Gödel-numbers in formalized set theory; I mean, atleast for sentences, surely we can talk about $\psi$ as a sentence in $\sf{ZF}$ without mentioning Gödel numbers, and we make a distinction between $\psi$ and $\ulcorner \psi \urcorner$, the latter being the Gödel encoding of the former; I don't know how to think about it when it comes to formulas with free variables, I mean, it "feels" like $ \ulcorner \chi(x) \urcorner$ is ill-defined without $x$ being something specific, perhaps I am mistaken.

So, it seems from your edit that, you would count the sentence $\psi$ as belonging to the metatheory, and only $\ulcorner \psi \urcorner$ as belonging to the formal language of $\sf{ZF}$? This is not my present understanding.
Addendum: Upon rereading the earlier parts of the same chapter in Kunen, I think you might be right.

@Ben123 (to your second to last comment) By "in set theory" I mean inside formulas in the formal language of set theory. In the course of the study of set theory, we of course talk about the formulas themselves too. We can talk about $\psi$ ("in the metatheory" if that sort of stipulation helps), but ZF can only talk about $\ulcorner \psi \urcorner.$ No, we can talk about formulas just fine.. $x$ is a variable and our coding allows us to talk about formulas with variables.

@Ben123 (To the last). Well, $\psi$ is a (metavariable representing) a sentence in the language of set theory. $\ulcorner \psi\urcorner$ is a term in (a definitional extension of) that same language that corresponds to it.

If you read my addendum, I changed my mind. I agree with your point, thanks for clarifying this =)

Thanks, your last comment clarifies things even more. I think what you just said should really be the answer to my question, not perhaps what you wrote in your post. Since what you just wrote clears up my confusion. Or well, you do actually mention it in your post (so I'll accept the answer). But I think the things you wrote before Edit are superflous to answer the question.

@Ben123 Ok, I edited it out.

@Ben123 I guess the thing I thought I was responding to, was "what exactly must $\chi(x)$ say to derive this contradiction", to which "it must satisfy the T schema" seems the natural answer.... because (whatever specific wording we use) it's not exactly clear at the outset what "it says $x$ is true" means.

Well, I sort of understood the argument (in Kunen) originally, I was mainly confused about how to interpret the free variable $x$ inside $\chi(x)$ when applied to $\ulcorner \psi \urcorner$, so in a sense yes, that was the question; I mean, if you think the first part is helpful to answer this then by all means keep it. Personally I think it was enough to understand that in formalized $\sf{ZF}$ we are only really talking about Gödel encodings, while e.g. sentences $\psi$ are in the metatheory.
